# VSCode debugger not showing array allocated with variables in cpp

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

[image: The debugger not reading the array allocated with variables]

The image sums up my question. When I explicitly allocate an array as-

```
int allocated[5][3] = {/values/};
```

They show up on the debugger just fine, as a 2d array with 5x3 values, but when I do it through variables-

```
int processes = 5; resources = 3;
int maxNeed[processes][resources] = {/values/};
```

no elements show up on the debugger.

Does it have something to do with VSC, or my code? please tell if there are any suitable extensions to fix this as well.

Edit- Using `#define processed 5 #define resources 3`
before main() also works just fine, but I why do I need to use #define for it to work? Why not normal variables?

Comment: That is using VLAs, which are not standard compliant. I'm not sure what debugger you are using, but I assume that the extension does not know how to deal with a non-standard feature

Comment: What if you make `processes` and `resources` both  `const`?